# How to place elements lower than sticky navbar in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I can't find information on how to use bootstrap to place all subsequent div lower than header.

I have it written like this:

```
<header className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark"> 
      <a className="navbar-brand px-3 fs-4" href="/">Todos</a>
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li className="nav-item active">
            <Link className="nav-link fs-4" to="/about">List <span className="sr-only"></span></Link>
         </li>
         <li className="nav-item active px-3 fs-4">
            <Link className="nav-link" to="/homepage"> Add <span className="sr-only"></span></Link>
         </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
```

[image]

And now that I have added a button to this page it appears in the upper left corner, not below. There is also an overlap if I go to another page . Since I am new to this, I will be glad to help.

```
<div className="mbtn"> 
    <button onClick={() => setType('books')} className="btn btn-outline-primary">Пользователи</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation for sticky navbars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#placement)? It lays out that you need to apply padding to the body.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.